# SQL Server ROLLBACK transaction took forever. Why?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactionscope

We have a huge DML script, that opens up a transaction and performs a lot of changes and only then it commits.

So recently, I had triggered this scripts (through an app), and as it was taking quite an amount of time, I had killed the session, which triggered a ROLLBACK.

So the problem is that this ROLLBACK took forever and moreover it was hogging a lot of CPU (100% utilization), and as I was monitoring this session (using exec DMVs), I saw a lot of waits that are IO related (IO_COMPLETION, PAGE_IO_LATCH etc).

So my question is:
1. WHy does a rollback take some much amount of time? Is it because it needs to write every revert change to the LOG file? And the IO waits I saw could be related to IO operation against this LOG file?
2. Are there any online resources that I can find, that explains how ROLLBACK mechanism works?

Thank You

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305277

Comment: if it toke a lot of time to DO stuff why do you think it wil not take a lot of time to UNDO the same stuff? Also the transaction can be hold by a lock/deadlock.

Comment: @jean I don't understand your comment.
Devio, Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3):

Based on another article on the DBA side of SO, ROLLBACKs are slower for at least two reasons: the original SQL is capable of being multithreaded, where the rollback is single-threaded, and two, a commit confirms work that is already complete, where the rollback not only must identify the log action to reverse, but then target the impacted row.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5233/is-rollback-a-fast-operation

Comment: Thanks, Mike. This does answer one part of my question. I was mostly interested in why the ROLLBACK was IO intensive. My answer has the reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I have found out about why a ROLLBACK operation in SQL Server could be time-consuming and as to why it could produce a lot of IO.

Background Knowledge (Open Tran/Log mechanism):
When a lot of changes to the DB are being written as part of an open transaction, these changes modify the data pages in memory (dirty pages) and log records (into a structure called LOG BLOCKS) generated are initially written to the buffer pool (In Memory). These dirty pages are flushed to the disk either by a recurring Checkpoint operation or a lazy-write process. In accordance with the write-ahead logging mechanism of the SQL Server, before the dirty pages are flushed the LOG RECORDS describing these changes needs to be flushed to the disk as well.

Keeping this background knowledge in mind, now when a transaction is rolled back, this is almost like a recovery operation, where all the changes that are written to the disk, have to be undone. So, the heavy IO we were experiencing might have happened because of this, as there were lots of data changes that had to be undone.

Information Source: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/sqlserver-logging/table-of-contents
This course has a very deep and detailed explanation of how logging recovery works in SQL Server.